# Packaging and Distribution of Java Program

Tags: installation, distribution, packaging

I need a way to package and distribute a Java program to a remote device.
Web Start is not ideal as it only distributes Jars and requires Web Server.
I need to distribute and run scripts during the installation and need some other types of files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best choice for building Windows installers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers)

Answer (score 0):

I use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) religiously for packaging and distributing java programs. I typically only use it to push to a single location (my server), but it is a rather flexible tool. In particular the deploy plugin is what I use to do the push.

However, if you want something that can be used as an installer to package a whole bunch of prerequisites alongside your application, take a look at [IzPack](http://izpack.org/).

Comment: I meant something like InstallShield in the Java world.

Comment: Anybody used "Nullsoft Scriptable Install System"?
Is it only Windows tool or can it work on Linux?